# Pandas Filtering: Returning True/False vs the Actual Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My dataframe:

```
df_all_xml_mfiles_tgther

      file_names     searching_for                                 everything
0          a.txt             where              Dave Ran Away. Where is Dave?
1          a.txt             candy                                mmmm, candy
2          b.txt              time                We are looking for the book.
3          b.txt             where                   where the red fern grows
```

My problem:

I am trying to filter for records that contain the words found in my search criteria. I need to go through 1 record at a time and return the actual record instead of just the word true.

What I have tried:

```
search_content_array = ['where', 'candy', 'time']
file_names_only = ['a.txt', 'b.txt']


for cc in range(0, len(file_names_only), 1):
     for bb in range(0, len(search_content_array), 1):

            stuff = `df_all_xml_mfiles_tgther[cc:cc+1].everything.str.contains(search_content_array[bb], flags=re.IGNORECASE, na=False, regex=True)`

            if not regex_stuff.empty:
                 regex_stuff_new = pd.DataFrame([regex_stuff.rename(None)])
                 regex_stuff_new.columns = ['everything']
                 regex_stuff_new['searched_for_found'] = search_content_array[bb]
                 regex_stuff_new['file_names'] = file_names_only[cc]

            regex_stuff_new = regex_stuff_new[['file_names', 'searched_for_found', 'everything']] ##This rearranges the columns

            df_regex_test =  df_regex_test.append(regex_stuff_new, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

The results I am getting are this:

```
    file_names  searched_for_found  everything
0        a.txt               where        True
1        a.txt               candy        True
2        b.txt               where        True
```

The results I want are this:

```
    file_names  searched_for_found                           everything
0        a.txt               where        Dave Ran Away. Where is Dave?
1        a.txt               candy                          mmmm, candy
3        b.txt               where             where the red fern grows
```

How do I get the actual value for returned results instead of just true/false?

Comment: Why do you retain the row with "candy"?

Comment: I just edited my post. Also, because it contains the word candy.

Comment: If the record contains the searched word found, anywhere in that row for the everything column, I want to keep the whole row.

Comment: Have you tried iterating using the values rather than the len? For example, `if where in string: # set searched_for_found = where`

Comment: Wouldn't that have the same effect? The goal is to go through the array 1 value at a time.

Answer (score 4):

Do this elementwise using a list comprehension.

```
df[[y.lower() in x.lower() for x, y in zip(df['everything'], df['searching_for'])]]
```

Or,

```
df[[y.lower() in x.lower() 
    for x, y in df[['everything', 'searching_for']].values.tolist()]]


  file_names searching_for                     everything
0      a.txt         where  Dave Ran Away. Where is Dave?
1      a.txt         candy                    mmmm, candy
3      b.txt         where       where the red fern grows
```

Comment: How exactly does the bottom one work? Are you telling me the value in searching_for for row 0 searches for, and only searches for, the row 0 value in the everything column?

I have been using python all of 4 months so I am still learning :)

Comment: @LunchBox The second method has `df[['everything', 'searching_for']].values.tolist()` returning a 2D list. Each row has 2 columns and is unpacked into x and y in a similar fashion as above.

Comment: I keep getting an error message ['where'] is not in index.

Comment: Still playing around with this before I check out another response.

Comment: Coldspeed, this solution works perfect, I figured out what I did wrong. Just out of curiosity, how did you come up with this solution? I was just asking because I have only been using Python for about 4 months, but I'm always eager to learn something new, so if you have a book or something you recommend?

Comment: @LunchBox I run a list of possible options through my head before figuring out the best one for you. I suppose that comes from having answered thousands of questions here already.

Answer (score 3):

Using `replace` and `str.contains`, PS I think cold's method is more succinct

```
s=df.everything.replace(regex=r'(?i)'+ df.searching_for,value='OkIFINDIT')
df[s.str.contains('OkIFINDIT')]
Out[405]: 
  file_names searching_for                  everything
0      a.txt         where Dave Ran Away Where is Dave
1      a.txt         candy                  mmmm,candy
3      b.txt         where    where the red fern grows
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the rows where it does not match with `np.nan` and then drop the `nan` values

```
 import numpy as np,re

 df.apply(lambda x: x if re.search(x[1], x[2],re.I) else np.nan,axis=1).dropna()

 file_names searching_for                     everything
0      a.txt         where  Dave Ran Away. Where is Dave?
1      a.txt         candy                    mmmm, candy
3      b.txt         where       where the red fern grows
```